# Why does Pathogen "magically" solve Vim syntax highlighting problems?

Tags: vim

I have these 3 lines in my `.vimrc`.

```
" keeping pathogen only for its 'syntax on' bug workaround
Bundle "tpope/vim-pathogen"
execute pathogen#infect()
```

I must have removed and re-added these 3 lines about a dozen of times now. I'm on latest version of Vim, and yet, for some reasons, some syntax highlighting isn't working correctly.

On MacOS, `Go` syntax highlighting isn't working, while on Arch Linux is. But on Arch, `coffeescript` isn't highlighted. For some reason, executing `pathogen#infect()` solves all problems on both platforms.

Its kind of like black magic to me, so I'm wondering why is that. Is there any better way to fix this problem?

**Answer:**
I have looked into my vimrc, and found the error. I had this line

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

`before` the Bundle's, where it should have been `after` the Bundles.

Comment: Where are the syntax files for these (under what directories)?

Comment: I use Vundler to install them. eg: Bundle "kchmck/vim-coffee-script". So files are then in ~/.vim/bundle/vim-coffee-script/ (ftplugin, syntax, etc...)

Comment: Check the `:scriptnames` output when it is working and when it is not working. I suspect some syntax file isn't loaded, when it isn't working

Comment: Thanks. In both cases syntax file is loaded, but without pathogen#infect() the filetype isn't being recognized. There seems to be no load of /ftdetect folder of plugin, when pathogen isn't started.

Comment: Those three lines are not a solution: the problem is either in your plugin manager ("Vundle", not "Vundler") or in your syntax script. Please show us the rest of your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/furion/dotfiles/src

Comment: Oh I found the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Vim does not look in .vim/bundle directories when starting. So it means that your "ftdetect" won't be loaded.

Pathogen looks into every bundle directory and load them.

If you want to see for yourself, start Vim twice, once with and once without `pathogen:infect()`, and type `:scriptnames` after boot. You'll see the list of loaded scripts.

You can even do a `:redir` to write the output into a file before invoking `:scriptnames` to get the exact diff of loaded scripts.

Comment: If he is using Vundle and it doesn't support ftdetect then he must either find another plugin manager or submit an issue to its author.